# убрать рамку вокруг button. windows forms

Tags: winforms

Доброго времени суток господа, у меня есть игра на которой появляются кнопки и пользователь должен успеть их нажать и за это он будет получать очки, кнопки именно появляются и исчезают, на каждой кнопке имеется своё изображение и нужно чтобы вокруг этого изображения не было рамки.[image: Как оно всё выглядит исходно]

[image: Во время работы приложения]

Comment: Можно использовать `Panel` вместо `Button`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Лучше бы вместо картинки код прилепили для наглядности.

Если нужно убрать рамку у кнопки, то так:

```
button.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
button.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
```

Comment: Сорри я думал, что код тут не так уж и важе, но помогло:) P.S. Лучший форум.