# Как убрать у кнопки черные внешние границы?

Tags: c#, winforms

как убрать черные границы у кнопки? Что бы было изображение без этих границ[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно XAML разметку вашей кнопки?

Comment: XAML? он разве не в WPF только? я на winforms делаю.

Comment: Извиняюсь, не посмотрел на метки. В winforms я профан и могу наговорить ерунды, поэтому лучше промолчу...

Comment: Возможно, [это](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47838167/6468198) поможет

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [убрать рамку вокруг button. windows forms](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/537168/%d1%83%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3-button-windows-forms)

Answer (score 4):

Если на скриншоте изображен компонент `Button`, у которого `FlatStyle=Flat`, можно использовать свойство [ButtonBase.FlatAppearance](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.buttonbase.flatappearance). Например, установить `BorderSize=0`.

Answer (score 3):

Не используйте кнопку, используйте `PictureBox`.

Открываете ToolBox, в поиске ищете PictureBox, выносите его на форму, далее в форме у Picturebox указываете путь к фотографии, в свойствах PictureBox нажимаете на вкладку события (events) и выбираете метод Click.